# Unexpected in-place sed behavior

Tags: sed

In trying to write a sed one-liner to replace instances of either

```
infra/helm/*/charts/*
```

or

```
infra/helm/*/charts/
```

In a file with "infra/helm/*/charts/*", a newline, and another line of text looking like so

```
infra/helm/*/charts/*
infra/helm/*/manifests/
```

I had success detecting these patterns and replacing them in a normal zsh (version: zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)) terminal window with this line of code

```
sed -E $'s/infra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/charts\\/(\\*)\*/infra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/charts\\/\\*\\\ninfra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/manifests\\//' myfile
```

I encountered a strange change in behavior when introducing the '-i' flag to  (GNU) sed. When I ran the exact same line, using this flag

(i.e.

```
sed -iE $'s/infra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/charts\\/(\\*)\*/infra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/charts\\/\\*\\\ninfra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/manifests\\//' datfile
```

)

I found that the file did not get modified. Normally I would assume this was due to some peculiarity with file permissions or the process being generated by invoking a script instead of a direct terminal entry, but strangely, I've confirmed

```
sed -iE $'s/infra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/charts\\/\\*/infra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/charts\\/\\*\\\ninfra\\/helm\\/\\*\\/manifests\\//' datfile
```

Works just fine. (To save eyestrain, the only difference in this line is that it accepts

```
infra/helm/*/charts/*
```

as a pattern match, without also accepting

```
infra/helm/*/charts/
```

)

Is anyone familiar with why this might be? FWIW, I've confirmed this behavior persists whether I use the aforementioned zsh version as the interpereter, *or* `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` as an alternative. It shouldn't be too difficult to find some workaround, but I'd like to improve my sed skills, so learning why this is happening would be really valuable to me.

I've attached a dump of the information from running

```
strings $(which sed)
```

below

```
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/sed/compile.c,v 1.28 2005/08/04 10:05:11 dds Exp $
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/sed/main.c,v 1.36 2005/05/10 13:40:50 glebius Exp $
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/sed/misc.c,v 1.10 2004/08/09 15:29:41 dds Exp $
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/sed/process.c,v 1.39 2005/04/09 14:31:41 stefanf Exp $
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU sed's `-i` option takes an optional argument, which is the suffix to use for backups. So `sed -iE … datfile` causes the old version of the file to be saved as `datfileE`. It doesn't match what you expect since you aren't passing the `-E` option, so the regex is parsed as a BRE and not an ERE.

The fix is to pass the options separately: `sed -i -E …` or `sed -E -i …`. (`-Ei` would also work, if you hate the next person who'll read your code.)

Alternatively, pass a backup suffix (`sed -E -i.bak …`), which lets your script work both with FreeBSD sed and with GNU sed. The suffix is necessary for BSD sed because its `-i` option has a mandatory argument, and must be in the same command line argument as the option (no space between `-i` and `.bak`) so that GNU sed treats it as an optional argument to `-i` and not a separate argument to `sed`. This has the side effect of creating backup files.

Comment: This was it, thanks!! Interestingly, `sed -i -E` seems to discard the space between flags and save a backup file as 'datfile-E', while still using BRE instead of ERE in my environment, but 'sed -E -i' and 'sed -E -i.bak' worked just fine

Comment: @swarles-barkley Then you're using BSD sed (on macOS, `/usr/bin/sed` is FreeBSD sed), not GNU sed.

Comment: Ah: can confirm: I was mistaken in thinking my GNU sed installation was the one being used